# Not able to show sqlite3(back end) error on Tkinter(front end)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, tkinter

I am working on a small project which is a school management project which simply does add, update, delete a student from the database

For the front end I am using Tkinter and for backend I am using sqlite3

Here I have roll number as the primary key, when I try to add the same roll number again it doesn't add into the database, and also it doesn't return anything on the front end.

So, I try to add showerror on the front end from the already exists roll number but it doesn't give me an error on the front end. For update and delete it showing an error on the font-end properly but for add only it is not working

Here is the code of save function(which is not working properly):

```
def save1():
con = None
try:
    Connection.cursor
    con = connect("pypro.db")
    try:
        rollno = int(enteno.get())
        name = entename.get()
        marks = int(entmrk.get())
    except:
        messagebox.showerror("EMPTY","enter the entry properly")
    try:
        
        if len(name)<2:
            return messagebox.showerror("ERROR","name should contain minimum 2 alphabets")
        if marks > 101:
            return messagebox.showerror("ERROR","marks should be less the 100")
    
    
        
    finally:
        entmrk.delete(0,END)
    cursor = con.cursor()
    sql = "insert into entry values ('%d','%s','%d')"
    args = (rollno,name,marks)
    cursor.execute(sql%args)
    
    if cursor.rowcount == 1:
        con.commit()
        msg = "RECORD Inserted"
        messagebox.showinfo("Inserted",msg)
    else :
        msg2 = "record does exists"
        return messagebox.showerror("ERROR",msg2)

    
        
    
    enteno.delete(0,END)
    entename.delete(0,END)
    entmrk.delete(0,END)
    enteno.focus()
except DatabaseError as e:
    con.rollback()
finally:
    if con is not None:
        con.close()
```

Here is the code of update function(which is working properly):

```
def update():
con = None
try:
    Connection.cursor
    con = connect("pypro.db")
    try:
        name = enteupname.get()
        marks = int(entupmrk.get())
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo("EMPTY","enter the entry properly")
    try:
        if len(name)<2:
            return messagebox.showerror("ERROR","name shoul contain minimum 2 alphabets")
        if marks >= 100:
            return messagebox.showerror("ERROR","marks should be less the 100")
        
    finally:
        entmrk.delete(0,END)
    rollno = int(entupeno.get())
    cursor = con.cursor()
    sql = "update entry set name='%s'where rollno= '%d'"
    args = (name,rollno)
    cursor.execute(sql % args)
    sql1 = "update entry set marks='%d' where rollno='%d'"
    args1 = (marks,rollno)
    cursor.execute(sql1%args1)
            
    if cursor.rowcount == 1:
        con.commit()
        msg = "RECORD UPDATED"
        messagebox.showinfo("update",msg)
    else:
        msg = "record does not exists"
        messagebox.showerror("ERROR",msg)

    entupeno.delete(0,END)
    enteupname.delete(0,END)
    entupmrk.delete(0,END)
    entupeno.focus()
except DatabaseError as f:
    con.rollback()
finally:
    if con is not None:
        con.close()
```

Please tell me if more information need to be added in this question.

Comment: The `try / except` will hide the error when inserting record with duplicate `rollno`.  Try printing `f` (the `DatabaseError`) in the `except` block.

Comment: put code with correct indentations.

Comment: maybe first run code without `try/except` or at least display error - `except Exception as ex: print(ex)` - to see what exactly makes problem.